# AWK print specific line & header

Tags: awk

I have a tab seprated file containing 1000+ rows and a header. The samples are defined by the value in column 1. I want to split the file into multiple files by column 1 but ALSO include header. Currently I can easily split into files using:

```
awk -F'\t' '{print>$1}' file.tab
```

and that will give me x files each containing all the rows pertaining to each sample. However I also want to include the header which is row 1 in each of these files. How can I go about doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Command:

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==1 { H=$0; next } {if(!d[$1]) print H>$1; print>$1; d[$1]=1 }' file.tab
```

Example input:

```
FN  DATA 
1.txt       abc
2.txt       bcd
1.txt       xyz
```

1.txt:

```
FN  DATA 
1.txt       abc
1.txt       xyz
```

2.txt:

```
FN  DATA 
2.txt       bcd
```

Comment: This is amazing!

Answer (score 3):

another similar `awk`

```
awk -F'\t' 'NR==1{h=$0; next} {print (a[$1]++?"":h ORS) $0 > $1}' file
```

the trick is keeping track of the headers that are printed indexed by the filename key.  If the file is sorted by key, there is an easier solution.